# How to call in django index.html fle for "GET" "POST" method for get data from id (fields)?

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In django I have create query like wise if someone want information:
In district parameter select Pune, then output gives data for pune district only.
for example :

http:127.0.0.1/api/?district=Pune

htt:127.0.0.1:8000/?crop = groundnut
and so on.

Next,I want to create a Html page for my starting django page(index.html)
if I runserver  http:127.0.0.1:8000/
display my html file , where Our models fields(paramter) is id and then  user submit the question "if" condition will be trigger and searching information for that parameters.
like wise:

District  =   __________ **submit**

gives data only for selected district name only

also

Crop   =   ______________  **submit**

gives data only for selected crop name only
likewise run this query 
http:/api/?crop=groundnut
if user choose crop name is groundnut,
if use choose crop name is guava, then http:/api/?crop=guava query will be run.

So,now I want to create index.html file multiple parameters works.(AND query will apply)
http:/api/district=Pune&crop=groundnut
So, I want to create html page which call to this query and its show me this type

Distrcit :  ________      Crop : __________     **submit**

**here is my models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from mongoengine import Document, fields


class Tool(Document):
    crop = fields.StringField(required=True)
    district = fields.StringField(required=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.crop

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural ='tool'
```

**project/urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from app.views import *

from routers import HybridRouter
router = HybridRouter()

router.register(r'tool', ToolViewSet, r"tool")

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls, namespace='api')),

    url(r'^$', index_view, {}, name='index'),

]
```

**app/views.py**

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

from rest_framework_mongoengine.viewsets import ModelViewSet as MongoModelViewSet

from app.serializers import *


class ToolViewSet(MongoModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ToolSerializer
    my_filter_fields = ('crop', 'district',) # specify the fields on which you want to filter

    def get_kwargs_for_filtering(self):
        filtering_kwargs = {} 
        for field in  self.my_filter_fields: # iterate over the filter fields
            field_value = self.request.query_params.get(field) # get the value of a field from request query parameter
            if field_value: 
                filtering_kwargs[field] = field_value
        return filtering_kwargs 

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Tool.objects.all() 
        filtering_kwargs = self.get_kwargs_for_filtering() # get the fields with values for filtering 
        if filtering_kwargs:
            queryset = Tool.objects.filter(**filtering_kwargs) # filter the queryset based on 'filtering_kwargs'
        return queryset


from .models import Tool
from django.shortcuts import render

def index_view(request):
    questions=None
    if request.GET.get('crop'):
        crop = request.GET.get('crop')
        questions = Tool.objects.filter(crop__icontains=crop)

        district = request.GET.get('district')
        query = Tool.object.create(crop=crop, district=district)
        query.save()

    return render(request, 'index.html',{
        'questions': questions,
    })
```

what I have to change in views.py file for index.html to get parameter and gives exact information after user click on submit button ?

**index.html**

```
<form method="GET">
    Crop: <input type="text" name="crop"><br/>
    Taluka: <input type="text" name="taluka"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form><br/><br/>


{% for question in questions %}
<p>{{question}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

can you help me how to get data and run the query ?
where I need to changes ?

Comment: Change this line like this **query = Tool.objects.create(crop=crop, district=district)** ,cf my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a **TYPO** error in this line :

```
query = Tool.object.create(crop=crop, district=district)
```

**object** should be **objects** ,like this :

```
query = Tool.objects.create(crop=crop, district=district)
```

Update your code like this :

from .models import Tool
from django.shortcuts import render

```
def index_view(request):
    questions=None
    if request.GET.get('crop'):
        crop = request.GET.get('crop')
        questions = Tool.objects.filter(crop__icontains=crop)

        district = request.GET.get('district')
        query = Tool.objects.create(crop=crop, district=district)
        query.save()

    return render(request, 'index.html',{
        'questions': questions,
    })
```

And, Update the save method of your **Tool** model like this :

```
class Tool(Document):
    crop = fields.StringField(required=True)
    district = fields.StringField(required=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.crop

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(Tool, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: its give error " type object 'super' has no attribute 'save'"

Comment: @KiranPrajapati You don't need to change your model structure. Just change the save method as per my answer.

Comment: Triveli, its give me new error  ValidationError at /

ValidationError (Tool:None) (Field is required: [ 'district, ])

Answer (score 1):

In your **index.html** file, change `{{question}}` to `{{question.crop}}`. You have to refer to the field (in your case `crop`) on the model you want to render on your page.

Also, the default manager is located at `Tool.objects` not `Tool.object`.

In your `models.py`, super should be `super(Tool, self)`. Also model `Tool` should inherit from `django.db.models.Model`. Your fields must be from `django.db.models`

```
class Tool(Model):
    crop = models.CharField()
```

Comment: it's give me same error  "    query = Tool.object.create(crop=crop, taluka=taluka)
AttributeError: type object 'Tool' has no attribute 'object'

Comment: you never mentioned about the error in the question.

Comment: oops sorry for that. any need changes in views.py for get input from index.html?

Comment: thanks for that, now gives me another error : super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: its give me another error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: if I use  super.save(Tool, self)  then gives me " type object 'super' has no attribute 'save'  this error .  if I use super(Tool,self) then its gives me  " NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132694/discussion-between-eskawl-and-kiran-prajapati).